# XAMARIN Selecting Tab in Tabpage through PRISM

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, tabpage

I have a tabbedpage view with 2 child contents inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="MultiPosApp.Services.Views.FoodAndBeverageView"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiPosApp.Services.Views"
            xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
            Title="Tables &amp; Menu Settings"
            BarTextColor="Black"
            BarBackgroundColor="LightGray"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="Black"
            x:Name="mytabpage">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <local:TablesView Title="TABLES" IconImageSource="Table.png" />
        <local:MenusView Title="MyMenu" IconImageSource="menusetting.png" />
    </TabbedPage.Children>
    
</TabbedPage>
```

When I try to use "SelectTabAsync" as shown below, the tabpage does not shift to MenusView

```
m_NavigationService.SelectTabAsync("MenusView");
```

Is there any mistake that I had been done?

Comment: where are you calling this code from?  From the docs: "The target tab and the calling tab must exist within the same TabbedPage instance."

Comment: Please look in Visual Studio's "Output" pane, where it shows Debug output as you run the app. When that line is executed, there is probably an error message because it can't find "MenusView". If there is an error, what exactly is the message?

Comment: @Jason I am calling from a viewmodel at which the tabbedpage was created.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve alright, let me try and see